# Concern on the number of VGDA in volume group including 2 PV inside

Tags: aix

i've got a question about the number of `VGDA` in **volume group including two PV** inside. As you know, there are total **`3`** VGDA allocated in that situation. One has 2 VGDA and the other has the last one. According to rule `at least 50% VGDA availabley`, if the PV having 1 VGDA crash, it doesn't matter. We still have 66% fine and VG can be varyon. But if the other PV doesn't work, the VG would never be brought up due to only 33% availability.

However from my understanding, why doesn't each PV include only one VGDA? That way, the VG can be varyon when either of 2 PVs crash.

Please help me out!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In that situation you must disable quorum checking (the 50% rule) via `chvg -Q n VGname`. This is common on the rootvg of AIX servers which typically uses two physical volumes and LVM mirroring.

You should check out the IBM Redbooks "Intro to LVM" and "LVM A-Z".

This question is better suited for Server Fault, it has nothing to do with programming.